# Turning projection into WKT string

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text

I have a grid which is constructed using the procedure described in this paper:

https://journals.ametsoc.org/view/journals/mwre/127/12/1520-0493_1999_127_2733_ctoasu_2.0.co_2.xml

[image: Irregular grid on a world map]

The procedure involves a transformation which moves the poles to two arbritary points.

Is it possible to encode this projection into a WKT string?

Comment: Well-Known Text is for common things. I doubt it would be of much use with "arbitrary".

Comment: I guess I can make this an answer (but someone feel free to!). The [EPSG registry] which is recommended to use as a basis for coordinate reference systems WKT strings, has no method/projection that would do this.

Comment: You are probably correct, but it would be nice with a definitive answer. The WKT format is flexible and can encode many "non-standard" projections with odd parameter choices. It also seems to be able to chain several mathematical transformations. What are the limitations?